# How can I access the custom class object from other method in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, class, object, methods

I have a custom class called "cell". I have to access to the its object from ibaction method. The last row is don't recognized

```
@implementation Screen
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    cell *player=[[cell alloc]init];

.
.
.
}


-(IBAction)Image:(Id)sender{
    [player sendData:57];    //   <-------------
```

Comment: Did you import custom subclass header file in Screen?

Comment: I have imported header file in screen.m and screen.h but don't work.

Comment: I solved by myself. In header file i must insert @class cell.